# JavaScript - passing variable from one function to another is undefined

Tags: sqlite, function, cordova, global-variables

in my example I'm trying to pass a variable (**var** ***ttoken***) from one function to another and save it to the SQLite. The coding environment is Phonegap (for android). Here is the procedure:

```
var ttoken;    // global var declaration
function handleLogin() {
var form = $("#loginForm");
var u = $("#username", form).val();
var p = $("#password", form).val();
if(u!= '' && p!= '') {
    $.post("http://localhost/login.php", {username:u, password:p}, function(data){
        if(data!='') {
            $.mobile.changePage("change_page.html");
            ttoken = data.token;
        } else {
            navigator.notification.alert("Error try again", function() {});
        }
    }, "json");
} else {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error, fields are emty", function() {});
}
return {tkn:ttoken};    // putting into array
openDB();
populateDB();
}

var db;
function openDB(){  // create database
    // 'Kurskoffer_DB' vol. 300 Kb
    db = window.openDatabase("Sample_DB", "1.0", "Samole DB", 300000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function populateDB(tx){    // create 'settings' table
    var tooken = handleLogin();    // accessing the variable ttoken
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, token TEXT NOT NULL, sound TEXT NOT NULL, vibra TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO settings(id, token, sound, vibra) VALUES (1, "'+tooken.tkn+'", "on", "on")');
}
```

Seems everything according variable passing rule is ok, but the insert result in the table for field token is **undefined**. Have anyone idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: The insert statement refers to tooken. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: @mlewis54 I'm surprised `tooken` even exists (otherwise it would be a TypeError)

Comment: @mlewis54 you are right the insert statement refers to `tooken`, because `tooken` variable contains the value from handleLogin() function, or i'm wrong?

Comment: @JanDvorak can you clarify please your comment, i'm just started to play with phonegap and javascript and could not fully understand you. thanks

Comment: @mlewis54 `tooken` is the object returned from `handleLogin`. The problem was that he was expecting `tooken.tkn` to be the value set in the post request callback.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.post` function is asynchronous, which means `handleLogin` will return before the `post` callback has fired, and `ttoken` remains undefined in the returned object.

Set up `handleLogin` to accept a callback, which will fire when the `post` has returned and `ttoken` has been populated.

Something like:

```
function handleLogin(callback) {
    var form = $("#loginForm");
    var u = $("#username", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val();
    if(u!= '' && p!= '') {
        $.post("http://localhost/login.php", {username:u, password:p}, function(data){
            if(data!='') {
                $.mobile.changePage("change_page.html");
                ttoken = data.token;
                if (callback) callback();
            } else {
                navigator.notification.alert("Error try again", function() {});
            }
        }, "json");
    } else {
        navigator.notification.alert("Error, fields are emty", function() {});
    }
}

function populateDB(tx){    // create 'settings' table
    handleLogin(function() {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, token TEXT NOT NULL, sound TEXT NOT NULL, vibra TEXT NOT NULL)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO settings(id, token, sound, vibra) VALUES (1, "'+ttoken+'", "on", "on")');
    });
}
```

Since `ttoken` is defined globally you don't have to worry about passing it around as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for advise,... tried your proposed code, result is still **undefined**. have you other idea?

Comment: Is the data returned from `login.php` JSON data? It looks like you're not parsing it, so `data` remains a string. Try inserting `data = JSON.parse(data)` just after `if(data!='') {`

Comment: yes, its returning the needed token, i also printed (via alert) it in order to be sure.

Comment: So `data` itself is the token? In that case you only need to set `ttoken = data` instead of `ttoken = data.token`

Comment: The format of `login.php` response is `{"token":"c4f7c735c458c129bb5c7f8d3612a820"}` and I don't need to parse it, because $.post($url, {$parameters}, function(), `"json"`) able to retrieve from json format everything what i need. The only thing what i need is to mention `data.token` (token - is index of json response) for getting the value of token

Comment: Ahh, true, sorry I overlooked that part. I've [set up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RJvf/1/) that shows this working properly, with a dummy `$.post` function, which just invokes the callback with the data object, and just `alert`s the SQL statements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23445/discussion-between-freejosh-and-dozent)